# "unsupported_grant_type" from Google's refreshing an access token (offline access) api

Tags: python, http, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

Per the [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline), if you want to refresh your access token, you can make an HTTP call to "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" with providing client_id, client_secret, grant_type, refresh_token.

Code:

```
user = User.query.filter_by(email='daniyaldehleh@gmail.com').first()  
with open('client_secret.json') as d:
    d = json.load(d)
thecredentials = { 
    'client_id': d['web']['client_id'],
    'client_secret':d['web']['client_secret'],
    'refresh_token':user.refresh,
    'grant_type': user.refresh,
    'redirect_uri': "http://localhost:5000/",
    'access_type':'offline'
}
req = requests.post(url='https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token', data = thecredentials)
print(req.text)
return str(req)
```

Despite adding 'redirect_uri' and 'access_type' based on some research, I keep on getting:

```
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: 1//04JBbHWUWxwS3CgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrZyyrHpxIoerJ4XZkAuGosXeeRHiYvdEQG7uF5EO5jWSC_-9mrRMAhmM30JHZvgyIhbM"
}
```

Comment: The error description is clear. You are not putting `refresh_token` as `grant_type`, but putting the refresh token.

Comment: isn't it the same thing? To be honest, I was confused by specifically. Should it be something like this:
`refresh_token = user.refresh
        thecredentials = { 
        'client_id': d['web']['client_id'],
        'client_secret':d['web']['client_secret'],
        'refresh_token':refresh_token,
        'grant_type': refresh_token}`

Comment: It would be great if you can clarify it by a sample code or something.

Comment: In this case, the value of `grant_type` is required to be `refresh_token`. So please modify `'grant_type': user.refresh,` to `'grant_type': 'refresh_token',` and test it again.

Comment: ohh okk. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 2):

For using refresh tokens the grant type should be: `grant_type = refresh_token`.

See https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization#using_the_refresh_token

Comment: did not work on my case... still returning Invalid grant_type